# My code is not adding data to the datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I have a problem where my code is not working. when the barcode is scanned it should add the item to the grid.

What I did is when the item is scanned it will appear in a textbox and its name will appear in another textbox and after that the item data will be added to the datagridview if the item is on stock.

this is my code.

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=hamo25.ddns.net;Initial Catalog=POS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=31045"))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Item_Code = @BarCode", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BarCode", code.Text));
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in receiptgrid.Rows)
                {
                    //Condition item out of stock
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetInt32(4)) > 1)
                    {
                        repeat:

                        name.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + reader.GetString(1));
                        string pname = reader.GetString(1);
                        string price = reader.GetString(2);
                        bool Found = false;
                        if (receiptgrid.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value) == reader.GetString(1) && Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Value) == reader.GetString(2))
                            {
                                row.Cells[2].Value = Convert.ToString(1 + Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value));
                                Found = true;
                            }
                            if (!Found)
                            {
                                receiptgrid.Rows.Add(pname, price, 1, price, date.Text);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                receiptgrid.Rows.Add(pname, price, 1, price);
                            }
                            //Multiplying the qty by the price ==================================================================
                            row.Cells[receiptgrid.Columns["Total"].Index].Value = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[receiptgrid.Columns["Price"].Index].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[receiptgrid.Columns["QTY"].Index].Value);
                            Thread.Sleep(500);
                            name.Text = string.Empty;
                            name.Select(0, 0);
                            name.ScrollToCaret();

                            name.Select(0, 0);
                            name.ScrollToCaret();
                            name.Text = string.Empty;
                        }
                        //contiton if item is out of stock
                        else if (Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetInt32(4)) == 1)
                        {
                            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("This item should be out of stock, Continue anyway?", "POS", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                            {
                                goto repeat;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("This Item is out of Stock", "POS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //Calculating the total =================================================
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < receiptgrid.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            sum += Convert.ToDouble(receiptgrid.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
        }
        Totaltxt.Text = sum.ToString();
        //end
        int qty = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < receiptgrid.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            qty += Convert.ToInt32(receiptgrid.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
        }
        Totalqty.Text = qty.ToString();
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: You are doing it the hard way.  Best method is to use a SQLDataAdapter and put results into a DataTable.  Then with one instruction you can move datatable to DGV  : datagridview1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: Nesting your connectionstring with `Sqlcommand` initializer and using `goto` makes your code pretty unreadable. Those conditions are also a bit confuse. It's not a good pratice to display your password like that.  

__Can you specify why your code isn't working? Is it returning an error? Which error?__

Also the `MessageBox.Show()` method is from Windows.Forms, and not from asp.net, isn't it?

Comment: If I had no fingers I could count the times I've ever needed a goto statement in C#.....